# mathematica getting input from user

Tags: input, wolfram-mathematica

'm new to mathematica. i have a small project: get an equation , a number n, a number x and a number y and a number h, then using euler formula calculate nTh iteration ... My code is :

```
f[x_,y_]=input["Please input f(x,y):"] 
n=input["Please input number of iterations:"] 
x0=input["Please input initial value x0:"] 
y0=input["Please input initial value y0:"] 
h=input["please input h:"] 
For[i=0,i<n,i++,y0=y0+f[x0,y0]*h;x0=x0+h]
```

but when i copy this code in mathematica 9; it just print some texts and end . it did not get any input from user.just print this:

```
input["Please input f(x,y):"]
input["Please input number of iterations:"]
input["Please input initial value x0:"] 
input["Please input initial value y0:"]
input["please input h:"]
```

and then end!

whould you help me ?

Comment: all mathematica builtin functions begin with capital letters

Comment: Use `Input` instead of `input`. Mathematica functions are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should write it in two separate parts.
I would write an initialize variables part then the for loop.
Functions in Mathematica need a delayed equals := and to you recieved the outputs you did because Mathematica doesn't allow you to input while the code is running. you also should suppress the output with a ;

```
f[x_,y_]:= ; %%write in f(x,y)
n= ; %%input number of iterations
x0= ; %%input initial value x0
y0= ; %%input initial value y0 
h= ; %%input h
```

An euler form of the solution is

```
euler:= Module[{ans, i, x, y, nsteps},
  ans = {{x0,y0}};x=x0;y=y0;nsteps=n;
    Do[(y=y+h*f[x,y];
       x=x+h; ans=Append[and,{x,y}]),{i,1,nsteps}];ans]
```

To view the euler forumal result do...

```
eulerans1 = euler
```